# How to call a function in a radgrid programmatically?

Tags: c#, function, telerik, radgrid

I'm creating a Radgrid of Telerik programmatically, but I don't know how to add a function for to update. This is my radgrid:

```
        RadGrid1.MasterTableView.EditMode = GridEditMode.Batch;
        RadGrid1.AllowPaging = true;
        RadGrid1.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
        RadGrid1.MasterTableView.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
        RadGrid1.PageSize = 15;
        RadGrid1.MasterTableView.CommandItemDisplay = GridCommandItemDisplay.Top;
        RadGrid1.MasterTableView.CommandItemSettings.SaveChangesText = "Guardar";
        RadGrid1.MasterTableView.CommandItemSettings.ShowSaveChangesButton = true;
        RadGrid1.MasterTableView.CommandItemSettings.ShowCancelChangesButton = false;
        RadGrid1.MasterTableView.CommandItemSettings.ShowAddNewRecordButton = false;
        RadGrid1.MasterTableView.CommandItemSettings.ShowRefreshButton = false;
        RadGrid1.AllowAutomaticUpdates = true;

        RadGrid1.UpdateCommand += RadGrid1_ItemUpdated();
```

The radgrid is working, to exception the last line. A radgrid created automatically from asp has a funtion like this:

```
    protected void RadGrid1_ItemUpdated(object sender, Telerik.Web.UI.GridUpdatedEventArgs e){}
```

How to I create a function and how to call it programmatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the code you've presented, I'm not sure why you couldn't just add the `protected void RadGrid1_ItemUpdated` method yourself, and then subscribe to it at runtime.

If you're going to be creating an unknown number of `RadGrid`s at runtime, and they each need to do something different, you could create a method for it to execute like this:

```
RadGrid1.UpdateCommand += (s,e) => { /* do update stuff */ }
```